# lastinsertId() not working with execute() while it works with exec()?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my complete php code except configuration file which contains only server information. this code through execution error while working with prepare to prevent sql injection and do not returns lastinserted id. Is there any solution to prevent sql injection by preparing statement and return last inserted id simultaneously.

```
<?php
$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once "$root/core/config/config.php";
class engine {
//constructing database connection based on configuration parameters 
function __construct() {

    if(DB_SERVER!="" && DB_USERNAME!="" && DB_PASSWORD!="" && DB_NAME!="") {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.'; dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            //$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT); PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION for testing db errors
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $url = pathinfo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . "/" . $path;
        $url = preg_replace("/\/\/+/", "/", $url);
        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $url;
        die("no database login");
    }
}
```

Here problem occures, if i prepare statement before execution it do not returns lastinsertid. through an error lastinsertid method error

```
//function to insert data in given table
public function insert($postcol, $postval, $table){
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $sql.=" ".$postcol;
    $sql.=" VALUES ".$postval;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $lastid = $stmt->lastInsertId();
    return($lastid);
}
```

If above function changed to direct execution it works fine as follows

```
//function to insert data in given table
public function insert($postcol, $postval, $table){
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $sql.=" ".$postcol;
    $sql.=" VALUES ".$postval;
    $stmt = $this->conn->exec($sql);
    $lastid = $stmt->lastInsertId();
    return($lastid);
}
```

below code is to strip inputs and forward data to insert function

```
public function formpro($post,$table,$action){
    switch($action){        
        case "insert" :     
        $numItems = count($post);
        $i = 0;
        $col="(";
        $val="(";
        foreach($post as $key=>$value) {
          if(++$i != $numItems) {
            $col.="`".$key."`, ";
            if(is_numeric($val)){
                $val.=$value.", ";
            }
            else{
            $val.="'".$value."', ";
                }
          }
          else{
            $col.="`".$key."`";
             if(is_numeric($val)){
                $val.=$value;
            }
            else{
            $val.="'".$value."'";
                }
          }
        }
        $col.=")";
        $val.=")";
        return(engine::insert($col,$val,$table));
    }
}
}
//to check class worked following data processed
$arr=array("user_name"=>"addya", "full_name"=>"ananda bhat", "password"=>"fattos", "rank"=>"3");
$engine=new engine();
echo($engine->formpro($arr,"users","insert"));
```

Comment: Isn't the query you are generating invalid? You also are still working on the prepared statement, right? If you don't parameterize it, it is no more secure than passing in the user data (which is in no way secure).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: I am new to php, i needed a pdo based form processor but cannot find it online so tried to write my own. @tadman

Comment: If you're new to PHP that's fine, but it's also a good reason to go with something established rather than painfully building your own ORM bit by bit. These things are wickedly complicated and full of tiny little gotchas that take a lot of time to understand and fix. A full [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) will give your application structure and a bunch of good community examples to work from. [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) are two great examples of that.

Comment: thanks to understand my problem but i think as a starter, I have to work with php and then go for a framework. may be it clear my way to use them. because without 0 we can't make 10, 100 or anything that contains 0. @tadman it's my opinion not my response to your suggestion.

Comment: Pick a framework, let it help you out, and learn PHP from the top down. You'll be significantly more productive and learn from good examples rather than crusty "tutorials" that don't teach you anything but obsolete and dangerous tricks. The code you have here is a long, long way from being truly production ready.

Answer (score 0):

`lastInsertId()` is not a method of `PDOStatement`, it's only a method of `PDO`. So even though you're using a statement to execute the query, you still have to call `lastInsertId()` on the connection.

```
public function insert($postcol, $postval, $table){
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $sql.=" ".$postcol;
    $sql.=" VALUES ".$postval;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $lastid = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
    return($lastid);
}
```